# make object from list

Tags: python, list, object

Ok so I have this code:

```
earth = makeWorld()

def turtle():
  list = ['Bill', 'Fred']
  for name in list:
    print name
    name = makeTurtle(earth)
```

What I am wanting to do is iterate through the list so I make a turtle for each name in the list. This is clearly wrong because the turtle only moves on name.forward() and uses 'name' not 'Bill' or 'Fred' in the list. So it's using the name not the list names. But I don't know how to rectify this?

Comment: Can you add an example of how you want to be able to use your function? It is difficult to identify your intent from your description.

Comment: Basically what Bckknight did below but with lists not dicts

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `name` other than to print it. You then *replace* the value in `name` with whatever `makeTurtle(earth)` returns.

From some [context](http://nebomusic.net/techlesson11-5.html) it looks like `makeTurtle()` creates a turtle object for you

```
turtle = makeTurtle(earth)
```

you can then use `turtle` to do something for that name, but you need to use `turtle` inside the loop body.

Alternatively, create a dictionary to connect names to turtles:

```
turtles = {name: makeTurtle(earth) for name in yourlist}
```

Now you have a mapping from names to turtle objects.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a dictionary to hold your name-object pairs:

```
earth = makeWorld()
names = ['Bill', 'Fred']

turtles = {} # empty dictionary
for name in names:
    turtles[name] = makeTurtle(earth)
```

Now you can use the `turtles` dictionary to access any of the named objects:

```
turtles['Bill'].do_something()
```

You can also construct the dictionary with a "dict comprehension" rather than creating it empty and adding the turtles to in in an explicit loop:

```
turtles = { name: makeTurtle(earth) for name in names }
```

As an aside, it's a bad idea to use `list` as the name of a variable, since that shadows the builtin list type. While you can often get away with it in a short function, it can cause very confusing errors if you do it at the top level of a module.

Comment: What if I wanted to just use the list?

Comment: @Danrex: I'm not sure what you mean by "use the list". You could pretty easily make a list of turtles that you index by integer, rather than a dictionary you index by name, but beyond that you'll need to explain more about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of your new turles using a list comprehension.

```
def turtle_generator(names):
    for name in names:
        yield (name, makeTurtle(earth))

def turtle_list(names):
    return [(name, makeTurtle(earth)) for name in names]


for (name, turtle) in turtle_xxx(['Bill', 'Fred']):
    print name
    print turtle
```

This will create a new turtle for each name, but it doesn't look like you're using the name in any way, so you might reconsider how to define makeTutle

Comment: So maybe I didn't explain myself enough. What i want is to iterate through the list to make a turtle by the first name, then the second and so on. So if my list is [John, Fred}  - I would make a turtle John and then a turtle Fred. Then I would want to be able to use the list name to ask all the turtles to follow directions.